# How to make Thunderbird auto-delete mails which *it* marks as spam?

Tags: thunderbird

It is clear how to tell ThunrBird to delete mails when ***I*** mark them as junk.

For a long time now, I have never seen a false positive - TB marking mail as junk when it is not.

I trust Thunderbird completely - how can I make it delete messages which ***it*** believes to be junk, so that I never even see them?

If it can't be done natively, then I will ask for a plug-in on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's wise to *completely* trust a program with no self-awareness. That being said, there's a possible solution that comes to mind which I haven't tried and that's not *exactly* what you're looking for, but that you might try and might find to be sufficient.

You can try setting the [per account settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-junk-spam-messages#w_per-account-settings) for the account in question to move new junk messages to the Junk folder, check "Automatically delete junk mail older than", and set the number of days as small as possible. Messages Thunderbird marks as junk should then be moved to the Junk folder and be deleted on there own, with the only side effect being their hanging around in the Junk folder until Thunderbird gets around to deleting them.

Answer (score -2):

Open Thunderbird and select Tools -> Options. Click on tab Security and select "When I mark message as junk:" and Delete them.

Comment: Did you read my question? I said that I know how to do that - "`When ***I*** mark message as junk`", The question is about when Thunderbird decides that they are junk, not me.